# Pycharm 5 проблема с русским языком в консоли

Tags: консоль, pycharm

Проверил. В предыдущей версии 4.5 русский язык отображается корректно, а в 5-ой версии кракозябры. А точнее вопрос в ромбе (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) - символ, который используется, когда значение символа неизвестно или не может быть выражено в Юникоде.
[image: REPLACEMENT CHARACTER]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная проблема наблюдалась в PyCharm 5.0.0: [PY-17568 Wrong encoding in PyCharm 5](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17568#)

И была решена в версии 5.0.1: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/pycharm-5-0-1-update-released/

Вчера (18.11.2015) вышел [PyCharm 5.0.2 EAP](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/pycharm-5-0-2-eap-is-available/), в данной версии проблем с кодировкой в консоли не наблюдается.

Для сравнения, PyCharm 5.0.0:
[image: 5.0.0]

PyCharm 5.0.2:
[image: 5.0.2]

Comment: Я пока переустанавливал windows вышла новая версия PyCharm. Поэтому я подумал, что переустановка помогла :)

Answer (score 3):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой и потратил несколько часов на гугление и указание кодировок во всех возможных местах.
В итоге помогло следующее:
**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **File Encodings** -> **Project Encoding** установить в *System Default* (в моем случае это установило кодировку windows-1251)
После этого русский нормально отображался
Но при этом у меня возникла другая проблема - эта кодировка менялась обратно на *UTF-8* при перезапуске PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Помогла переустановка windows.

*Вернее пока я переустанавливал windows, вышла новая версия PyCharm 5.0.1 и проблема исчезла.
insolor всё объяснил.

Comment: У меня та же проблема с PyCharm 5, но я не готов к столь кардинальным мерам)